# CakePHP 3 update of database by external program

Tags: cakephp

My question relates to CakePHP 3.x and the problem of blocking selected pages and blocking all user sessions while the database is updated. The database of the website is in my case updated by the external program (I have influence on its code). The time of the update is long aproximatelly 40 minutes and I do not have any good idea how should I solve the following issues:

a) How should I automatically block some selected pages while the update takes place? More specifically, only while the update of the database is conducted no-one should be able to enter some pages eg.:

```
www.mypage/information/updateinfo 
www.mypage/information/updatestatus
```

The user could be automatically redirect to the "update information page" or be informed otherwise.

b) How from the external program can I "throw away" all logged users and destroy all other sessions in the website? During the update no-one can be logged and no-one can have the ongoing session because the data in the database is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

- [Put the user session in the DB](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions)
- Have a table or lock file both apps have access to

  - When updating first delete all entries in the session DB table from your updating app
  - Then set the lock file / DB config lock entry
- Check for the lock, redirect as needed

Comment: This is a good answer for a part of problem B. This should work for the logged users but does not solve the other ongoing sessions - without autentication

Comment: It does destroys in fact *all* sessions because *all* sessions are managed through that DB session table then. You might want to be more precise in your question.

Comment: I just implemented the proposed solution and yes point B of my question is fully answered